# In place shift in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert below text file:

```
4100,123.45-,6789.66-
4152,1234.11,6789.11
```

(And many more records)

To

```
4100,-123.45,-6789.66
4152,1234.11,6789.11
```

Note that the input file have minus sign at the end of the number, I would like to correct it using Linux command.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed!

```
sed 's/\([0-9.]*\)-/-\1/g' file
```

To do it in-place, use `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9.]*\)-/-\1/g' file
```

It uses regular expressions. For this case:

- `s/x/y/g` -- substitute any occurence of `x` with `y`
- `[0-9.]*` -- match any number of digits or dots
- `\(\)` -- match group and bind to `\1`, `\2`, etc. in replacement expression
- `-` -- match minus

So this expression matches any number of digits or dots, grouped to `\1`, ending with minus and puts minus at before that group.

Answer (score 1):

A `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\d+?\.?\d+)-/-\1/g' inputfile
```

Comment: To allow single digit numbers, change one of the `+` to a `*` -- your regex cannot match `1-`